# Android SecurityException on PDF Send Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, permission-denied, securityexception

I'm getting the following exception during an `ACTION_SEND` intent with a data type `application/pdf`:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=application/pdf flg=0x3080000 cmp=com.adobe.reader/.ARSendForSignature (has extras) }
```

This brings up a dialog to choose the desired application to receive the PDF. I believe the `SecurityException` is being thrown when a user chooses Adobe Reader from the list, although it appears to be opening specifically the `ARSendForSignature` activity.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are encountering a bug in the Adobe Reader app, or a bug in Android, depending upon your perspective.

The Adobe Reader `ARSendForSignature` activity supports the `ACTION_SEND` `<intent-filter>`, but they explicitly have `android:exported="false"`, which denies anyone but them the ability to start that activity.

Either:

1. Adobe Reader should not have that `<intent-filter>`, or
2. Adobe Reader should not have marked it as not exported, or
3. The Android chooser should filter out non-exported activities

Long-term, the answer should be #3 -- I'll work on reproducing this problem and will file an issue, assuming there isn't already one. Short-term, Adobe can fix this faster than we can fix a couple hundred million devices. :-)

Comment: Reproduced and issue filed: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29535

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and for filing the bug. Is there any way I can at least catch the exception to prevent my app from crashing? Since it's not thrown by the `startActivity` call with the send intent, but rather the `startActivity` call within the chooser...is there any way to do this?

Comment: @ashughes: Based on the stack trace I am seeing, my guess is "no", outside of whatever global exception handler you might have in place (e.g., for ACRA).