# Using Zxing Barcode scanner causes SecurityException

Tags: android, android-intent, barcode, zxing, securityexception

I use  Zxing Barcode Scanner in my app via launching an `Intent` so that I can scan a barcode and get the data back to my app. Very basic stuff; it has worked for a long time no problem. I recently got an error report through Play with the following stack trace:

```
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent 
{ act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN cmp=com.ups.mobile.android/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity } 
from ProcessRecord{421bafc8 11687:edu.byu.dburner.lendablefree/10141} 
(pid=11687, uid=10141) not exported from uid 10137
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1736)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1383)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3281)
    at edu.byu.dburner.lendable.xxxxx.xxxx$2.onClick(xxxxxx.java:539)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3644)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14313)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As far as I can tell with the stack trace, there is some issue with `com.ups.mobile.android`, which is the UPS app that also utilizes the Zxing app. I tried installing the UPS app and mine on the same phone and triggering the `onClick` event where the problem occurred. Nothing significant occurs, except a chooser asking me to pick the Barcode Scanning app or the UPS app to perform the `Intent`. My only guess would be that both of our apps are having some sort of collision where only one person can use the Barcode Scanner package at a time, resulting in a SecurityException. But that doesn't make much sense to me since I can do it no problem, and I imagine many people have multiple apps that use Zxing installed with no issue.

Does anyone have an insights into what causes this error and what I can do to fix it?

EDIT:
Per SeanOwen's comment, if you have this trouble with Barcode Scanner specifically, really do use `IntentIntegrator`. They provide a built-in method `setTargetApplications`. You can use this to make the `Intent` only use the actual Barcode Scanner app: `setTargetApplications(IntentIntegrator.TARGET_BARCODE_SCANNER_ONLY);` Easy as pie.

Comment: my guess is that the user had the UPS app installed and chose that instead of BarcodeScanner when your app launched the intent. However I  have no idea why that would raise a security exception. Though I do think it would cause some sort of trouble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPS Mobile is not linking to the Barcode Scanner app, but apparently have baked in its source code. This is not terribly shocking, even if it is unsupported and not recommended by the ZXing team.

However, the UPS Mobile developers then did two things:

1. They kept the same `<intent-filter>`, particularly where they are advertising that they are handling the `com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN` action, despite the fact that they are not actually that app
2. They marked the activity as not exported

Courtesy of [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29535), the chooser will still show their activity, despite the fact that theirs is not exported and therefore cannot be launched.

UPS Mobile either should be linking to Barcode Scanner the way you are, or not advertising this action. And, of course, this bug should get fixed.

Unfortunately, the only workaround I can think of would be for you to add in your `Intent` the actual package name for Barcode Scanner (`com.google.zxing.client.android`) to try to limit it to that app only.

This is reminiscent of [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319928/android-securityexception-on-pdf-send-intent/10320136), that led to [a blog post of mine](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/25/how-isolated-adobe-reader-activity-issue.html), that obviously was insufficient to educate UPS, so I'll probably blog on this again...

Comment: This is one of the big reasons we strongly discourage copy-and-paste of Barcode Scanner. It's typically the less-than-competent developers that need to copy, and they don't make necessary changes like the one you outline. Thanks for bringing it to light.

If you use the supplied `IntentIntegrator` code in zxing (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent), it will by default only select Barcode Scanner or Barcode Scanner+, using the mechanism you cite. Another reason to use our integration code rather than roll your own...

Comment: @SeanOwen: Ah, I hadn't looked inside `IntentIntegrator` recently -- glad to hear that you're tying it to your own project.

Comment: @SeanOwen: I hadn't been using `IntentIntegrator`, but was just handling it myself. I appreciate the further education.

Comment: I just had a similar issue but the error log refers not to UPS, but to: cn.menue.barcodescanner/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.  And the IntentIntegrator does refer to Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN") in its initiateScan().

Comment: @Yar: I cannot reproduce your problem using `IntentIntegrator`. Even with that app installed, `IntentIntegrator` will choose Barcode Scanner. I tested it using this `IntentIntegrator` client: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/ZXing

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, me neither. A menu appears where you can select Barcode Scanner or the other app. Even with my "old" IntentIntegrator (C) 2009 ZXing authors, by S. Owen, F. Lin, I. Potoczny-Jones, B. Drehmer. I don't know how an user of mine got the error.